# When adding List to a nested List, why do you need to use constructor to make a new list instance instead of just adding an existing list?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm using backtracking algorithm to solve permutaion with duplicate values in leetcode. I put my solution below. Basically my idea is to use a temporary LinkedList(temp) to construct possible permuation and when its length equals the length of the array then add it to the answer List>. My question is , when adding the temp list to the ans list, if I just use **ans.add(temp)** (as in committed line) the ans list will just end up with a list of empty list. And I found the correct solution is to use **ans.add(new LinkedList(temp))**.

## My question is

1.Is it using constructor of LinkedList class?
2.Why can't I just add the temp list into the ans list? What's going on behind the scene?

```java
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permuteUnique(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new LinkedList<>();
        if(nums.length==0)
            return ans;
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int num : nums){
            map.put(num, map.getOrDefault(num,0)+1);
        }

        backtracking(map,ans,new LinkedList<Integer>(),nums.length);
        return ans;

    }

    public void backtracking(Map<Integer, Integer> map, List<List<Integer>> ans, LinkedList<Integer> temp, int length){
        if(temp.size()==length){
            //ans.add(temp); why doesn't this work???
            ans.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(temp));
            return;
        }
        for(Integer key: map.keySet()){
            int num = map.get(key);
            if(num==0)
                continue;
            manipulate(map,key,-1);
            temp.add(key);
            backtracking(map,ans,temp,length);
            manipulate(map,key,+1);
            temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
        }

    }

    public void manipulate(Map<Integer, Integer> map,int key, int delta){
        map.put(key, map.get(key)+delta);
    }
}
```

Comment: See the top answer here [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](//stackoverflow.com/a/19843507) under the topic "Adding the Same Object" and keep in mind that `ans.add()` doesn't copy anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing:

```
ans.add(temp)
```

You're adding the same list over and over, because in Java, your **temp** param acts as "reference" (is a pointer). Therefore, you need to instantiate a new LinkedList<> to make it work as different objects and fulfil your list